# Only one handler for the PrintTaskRequested event may be registered at a time UWP print error

Tags: uwp, win2d

In the `Mainpage` constructor, I have this line :

```
PrintManager.GetForCurrentView().PrintTaskRequested += OnPrintTaskRequested;
```

I have a button in menubar for printing with this click event handler:

```
CanvasPrintDocument printDocument;

public async void PrintButtonClick()
{
    if (printDocument != null)
    {
        printDocument.Dispose();
    }

    printDocument = new CanvasPrintDocument();

    printDocument.Preview += (sender, args) =>
    {
        sender.SetPageCount(1);
        PrintPage(args.DrawingSession, args.PrintTaskOptions.GetPageDescription(1));
    };

    printDocument.Print += (sender, args) =>
    {
        using var ds = args.CreateDrawingSession();
        PrintPage(ds, args.PrintTaskOptions.GetPageDescription(1));
    };

    try
    {
        await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
private void PrintPage(CanvasDrawingSession ds, PrintPageDescription printPageDescription)
{
    //
}
```

This button also has Keyboard accelerator CTRL + P.

Now, this works for me in my machine, in debug and release mode, no problem.

However, I am getting some crash reports of my app that says the error:

> A method was called at an unexpected time.
>
> Only one handler for the PrintTaskRequested event may be registered at
>   a time.

I don't get it how the `PrintTaskRequested` event is registered more than once at a time. Since the event handler registration code is in the constructor.

I don't have any other printing logic in my app.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the event registration occurs in the constructor of MainPage, you can check whether the application may navigate to MainPage multiple times.

But a more common approach is to cancel the event before registering it.

```cs
PrintManager.GetForCurrentView().PrintTaskRequested -= OnPrintTaskRequested; 
PrintManager.GetForCurrentView().PrintTaskRequested += OnPrintTaskRequested;
```

This ensures that only one print event is always registered.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. Just one more thing: the `Mainpage` has `NavigationCacheMode =Requred`, so even if the user Navigate back to Mainpage multiple times, it shouldn't create a new Mainpage , right?

Comment: Yes, the instance will be reused after caching, without rebuilding.